# Why does MemberNotNull not work for override of properties?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

The message `warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument` is issued on the call to `Process()`. A way to fix is to mark it with `MemberNotNull`.

If there is no override in the Derived class then MemberNotNull works as expected.

Why does the compiler still warn if an override exists?

What would be a better way to suppress this warning?

````
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace Tests
{
    class Base
    {
        public virtual string? Member { get; set; }

        [MemberNotNull(nameof(Member))]
        public void Validate()
        {
            if (Member is null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Prop is null");
            }
        }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        public override string? Member { get; set; } // warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class MemberNotNullTests
    {
        static void Process(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMemberNotNull()
        {
            Derived instance = new();
            instance.Validate();
            Process(instance.Member);
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: `string` is already a nullable type, using `string?` should be invalid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#8311-nullable-value-types

Comment: @Janilson he's using [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) under which `ReferenceType?` is valid syntax. Attributes such as [`MemberNotNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullattribute?view=net-6.0) are part of the support for this feature.

Comment: I think an overrided member need be validated in the derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is non-authoritative)

From what I can tell, this behaviour is likely by-design *for now*, apparently.

Here's some relevant sources:

- [Here's the LDM that lead to the creation of `[MemberNotNull]` in the first place](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2020/LDM-2020-02-05.md#nullability).
- [Here's the PR from February 2020 that added support for `[MemberNotNull]` to Roslyn, the C# compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/41675).
- [Here's a (currently open) GitHub issue about *the reverse* scenario](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/56531): where a derived-type cannot use `[MemberNotNull]` to make assertions about members inherited from a supertype.

  - [Here's an earlier dupe of that issue that was actually closed as *by design*](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/54658), except with a Roslyn team-member stating for the record:

    > [**@jaredpar 2021-07-07**](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/54658#issuecomment-875588662): The C# language design team decided that `MemberNotNull` could only apply to declared members on the type where the attribute was used.
  - So even though he's referring to use of `[MemberNotNull]` on a derived-type referring to supertype members, it also precludes `[MemberNotNull]` being used in a supertype to refer to *possibly overridden* subclass members.
  - Remember that overridden members don't *share identity* with their corresponding `abstract` or `virtual` members in their supertype (whereas inherited nonvirtual members do share identity), so (as far as the analyzer is concerned) [MemberNotNull( "Member" )]`can only refer to`Base.Member`and not`Derived.Member`.
- It can certainly be argued that it *should* be supported, I suspect it's a consequence of the decision to use the same member lookup code as the long-existing `DefaultMemberAttribute`.

[This is indirectly mentioned in the LDM notes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2020/LDM-2020-02-05.md#nullability), but they don't explain *why* or how they came to that decision, but I assume because it would save time and result in predictable behaviour (or in this case... *unexpected* behaviour):

> We propose that the lookup rules for resolving the names in these instances would be similar to the rules for the `DefaultMemberAttribute`.

Curiously, in the PR code-review notes *the reverse* scenario is discussed where `MemberNotNull` is used in a subclass to assert that non-overridden inherited members are not-null - but I can't find a mention of the obvious reversal of that, which is what we're concerned:

> [@jcouv 2022-02-25](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/41675#discussion_r384214034): Note that a type can only mark its own members as not-null, but not its base's.

Answer (score -2):

1. Why you are using string?
2. Why do you write validation inside the class that is going to be validated?
3. Are you sure that the derived class should override property?

I could recommend having:

```
class Base
    {
      public virtual string Property {get;set;}
    }
    class Derived: Base
    {
      public override string Property {get;set;}
    }
    // can be as service
    public interface IValidator<T> where T: Base
    {
      public bool IsValid(T item);
    }
    
    class Validator : IValidator<T>
    {
      public bool IsValid(T obj) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Property);
    }
```

In tests:

```
        Derived instance = new();
        Validator validator = new();
        validator.Validate(instance);
        Process(instance.Member);
```

Comment: In the code where I had this issue the property was abstract and string was just an example. I want validation to be part of the class so it is responsible for its own valid state. Maybe a generic method could work around the problem. It would be good if the person down-voting your answer would leave a comment.